# How to kill hung metro application?

Tags: task-manager, modern-ui, alarm

Suppose one of metro application hanged and doesn't respond

How to kill it?

Here is hung alarms application:

[image]

It does nothing on `Dismiss` click.

How to kill it? I don't apparently see any `Alarm` entry in Task Manager

Comment: Meat is hung; people are hanged.

Comment: can you move the Window?  Of course that does not look like an application but a notification window.  Are you sure its the actual application that is hung up?

Comment: @Ramhound suppose it is; how to kill it?

Comment: @Dims - If you log in and out of the user.  If you determine what process it is a notification window for, you can kill that process, I wouldn't know.  You can restart the machine, try restarting Windows Explorer, determine if it has process of its own and kill that.

Comment: So, there are no other ways to kill hanged metro application except these you listed? This notification window is from "Alarms" application. How to know it's process? If that would normal application, I would probably know it's EXE name.

Answer (score 0):

Open [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and look under the svchost.exe with the command line `C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch`. Here you can see some `WWAHost.exe`. Hover the mouse over them to see which process belongs to your app, select it, do a right click and and terminate it.